# Gradle add nested subproject from a multi-module project as dependency of another subproject

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, multiple-projects

I have a complex, but interesting situation. This is a tree diagram of my folder structure:

```
root
|___ settings.gradle
|___ p1
|___ p2  // depends on p3/sp1
|___ p3
|____|___sp1
|____|___sp2
```

I hope that explains the situation.

Now how would I add `sp1` as a dependency of `p2`?

So far in my root `setting.gradle`, I have

```
rootProject.name = root
include 'p1'
include 'p2'
include 'p3'
```

In `p2` build.gradle, I have:

```
dependencies {
    compile project (':p3:sp1')
}
```

But doing this still does not resolve the dependencies in `p2`; I still get errors about missing definition.

How do I fix this?

*Just an aside, how would I resolve other dependencies `sp1` might have. Like if it depends on `sp2`, do I need to declare this somehow even though it is already resolved within `p3`?*

Comment: Hi! Have you solve this problem? I am finding for example for resolve similar problem

Comment: @iamthevoid I think the accepted answer should work. Did you try it?

Comment: Yep, I've already did same.

Comment: By the way, I have the question. By default modules of my submodule use settings.gradle, build.gradle of parent project, but not the same files of submodel root project. Is there way to force using build.gradle and settings gradle of submodel root project?

Comment: @iamthevoid Gradle does not support having multiple `settings.gradle` in one gradle project (regardless of subprojects). You can use [`composite build`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) projects to accomplish this though

Comment: @iamthevoid if your subprojects are not composite builds, then they should include their own `build.gradle`, but the parent project can configure each subproject by using the `subproject` closure

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming project `sp1` and `sp2` are `subprojects` of project `p3`, if you want to do:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':p3:sp1')
}
```

Then you need to change your `settings.gradle` to:

```
rootProject.name = root

include ':p1'
include ':p2'
include ':p3'    // Keep this if this folder contains a build.gradle
include ':p3:sp1'
include ':p3:sp2'
```

Comment: It's a bloody shame that Gradle has not documented this more properly. I find the tutorial at https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/ misleading and the official documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html missing some crucial information. With Maven multi-module builds are trivial (and recursive child modules are simple); with Gradle it's most definitely not.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add the answer for those who might be looking, in your settings.gradle you will have

```
include ':p1',':p2',':p3:sp1',':p3:sp2'
```

if sp1 depends on sp2

then add dependency on sp1's gradle as

```
dependency {
   compile project(":p3:sp2")
}
```