# Attempting to resolve interdependencies in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android Project where I'm trying to setup one workspace with the following dependencies:

```
<master project>
|__master_library
|____| master_library_module_1
|____| master_library_module_2
|____| master_library_module_3
|____| master_library_module_4
|__sample application
|__3rd_party_plugin_libs_dir 
|____| library_plugin_1 (implementation dependency on master_library)
|____| library_plugin_2 (implementation dependency on master_library)
|____| library_plugin_3 (implementation dependency on master_library)
```

I am struggling on the proper way to define the root settings.gradle, and the references within the 3rd party plugins libraries to have an implemetation dependency on another submodule within the same project.

I've added every module to the root settings.gradle, per links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432598/gradle-add-nested-subproject-from-a-multi-module-project-as-dependency-of-anothe), but there is little documentation on how to reference somehting that is actually 'upstream' as far as the project is concerned.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this, Android studio does not like rouge settings.gradle even present.

- Define all modules in the root project settings.gradle
- Make sure to delete any additional settings.gradle that may exist. Having blank files simply does not work and Android Studio behaves badly.